# Any way to speed up drawing on bitmap canvas?

Tags: delphi, canvas, bitmap, delphi-xe7

Part of my application is drawing draft of graphic forms, mostly user input forms, with many Edit boxes. I draw on bitmap and save as PNG, all part of the report process, so nothing is drawn to the application form.
I draw all controls, Edit boxes, Radio buttons, checkboxes...

The longest part of the drawing is of course drawing Edit boxes, because of the huge number of them. I have a typical process that draw 1M Edit boxes, on around 70K forms.

I draw a very simple Edit box:

1. Basic rectangle, Pen width = 1
2. Add left and top additional lines, to get the feeling of indented control.
3. Add text, if needed

I'm attaching a screenshot of simple Edit control, with Zoomed in, so the extra left and top lines are visible.

[image]

Here is the code for DrawEdit, that draws 1M Edit boxes and it takes 20s. **Is there anyway to speed up the process?**

```
procedure DrawEdit(myCanvas:TCanvas; vLeft, vTop, vWidth, vHeight: integer; const vText: string; vCenterText:boolean=false);
begin

  // basic rectangle
  pPoint.x := vLeft; pPoint.Y := vTop;
  myCanvas.Pen.Width := 1;
  myCanvas.PenPos := pPoint;
  myCanvas.Pen.Color := $0099A8AC;
  myCanvas.LineTo(vLeft + vWidth, vTop);
  myCanvas.LineTo(vLeft + vWidth, vTop + 1);
  myCanvas.Pen.Color := $00E2EFF1;
  myCanvas.LineTo(vLeft + vWidth, vTop + vHeight - 1);
  myCanvas.LineTo(vLeft, vTop + vHeight - 1);
  myCanvas.Pen.Color := $0099A8AC;
  myCanvas.LineTo(vLeft, vTop);

  // again top border
  pPoint.x := vLeft + 1; pPoint.Y := vTop + 1;
  myCanvas.PenPos := ppoint;
  myCanvas.Pen.Color := $00646F71;
  myCanvas.LineTo(vLeft + vWidth, vTop + 1);

  // again left border
  ppoint.x := vLeft + 1; ppoint.Y := vTop + 1;
  myCanvas.PenPos := ppoint;
  myCanvas.Pen.Color := $00646F71;
  myCanvas.LineTo(vLeft + 1, vTop + vHeight - 1);

  if vText<>'' then
  begin
    // clear area for text - white background
    myCanvas.Font.Color := clblack;
    myCanvas.Brush.Color := clWhite;
    rRect.Left := vLeft + 2;
    rRect.Top := vTop + 2;
    rRect.Right := vLeft + myCanvas.TextWidth(vText);
    rRect.Bottom := vTop + myCanvas.TextHeight(vText);
    myCanvas.FillRect(rRect);

    If Not vCenterText Then
      Winapi.Windows.TextOut(myCanvas.Handle, vLeft + 4, vTop + 2, PChar(vText), Length(vText))
    else
      Winapi.Windows.TextOut(myCanvas.Handle, vLeft + (vWidth div 2) - (myCanvas.TextWidth(vText) div 2), vTop + (vHeight div 2) - (myCanvas.TextHeight(vText) div 2), PChar(vText), Length(vText));
  end;

end;
```

and here is the test I use.The test is not ideal, since real Edit boxes are different sizes, but this is my test to test different optimizatino options.

```
procedure TForm1.Button3Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  i, t1, t2: integer;
  myBitmap: TBitmap;
begin

  myBitmap := TBitmap.Create;
  try
    myBitmap.SetSize(500, 500);
    myBitmap.PixelFormat := pf24bit;

    t1 := GetTickCount;
    for i := 1 to 1000000 do
      DrawEdit(myBitmap.Canvas, 10, 10, 100, 50, 'Edit box', true);
    t2 := GetTickCount;

  finally
    myBitmap.Free;
  end;

  button3.Caption := inttostr(t2 - t1);

end;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

GDI is efficient for drawing to devices, however, for in memory bitmap work it carries a significant overhead.

You'd do better avoiding the GDI layer and do this directly to an in memory raster image. I recommend the graphics32 library for this. Switching to that should yield a very significant performance gain.

Another thing you might do is split the work into multiple tasks and take advantage of multi-threading. You'd want to draw to distinct bitmaps, and then splice together at the end.

Comment: Thank you, I downloaded last Graphics32 and looked at the samples and I'm confused as it seems quite close but completely different drawing methods. Should I use TBitmap32, TCanvas32.. .LineTo, LineToS... where is Pen.Width replacement... if you can direct me to a simple example or even give me an example based on my code, I could then go on. Documentation doesn't provide a lot of info for someone who is trying to use it the first time. I changed TBitmap to TBitmap32 and tested same code to draw on TBitmap32.Canvas and timings is the same.

Comment: Thank you @david, using Line from Graphics32 is 3x faster.

Answer (score 2):

I use `Line` to draw on TBitmap32, from Graphics32 and the result is 3x faster than drawing on TBitmap.Canvas:

```
procedure DrawEdit32(BM32: TBitmap32; vLeft, vTop, vWidth, vHeight: integer; const vText: string; vCenterText: boolean = false);
begin

  // basic rectangle
  BM32.Line(vLeft, vTop, vWidth, vTop, $0099A8AC);
  BM32.Line(vWidth, vTop, vWidth, vTop + vHeight, $00E2EFF1);
  BM32.Line(vWidth, vTop + vHeight, vLeft, vTop + vHeight, $00E2EFF1);
  BM32.Line(vLeft, vTop + vHeight, vLeft, vTop, $0099A8AC);

   // again top border
  BM32.Line(vLeft + 1, vTop + 1, vWidth, vTop + 1, $00646F71);

  // again left border
  BM32.Line(vLeft + 1, vTop + 1, vLeft + 1, vTop + vHeight, $00646F71);

  if vText <> '' then
  begin
    // clear area for text - white background
    BM32.Font.Color := clblack;
    rRect.Left := vLeft + 2;
    rRect.Top := vTop + 2;
    rRect.Right := vLeft + BM32.TextWidth(vText);
    rRect.Bottom := vTop + BM32.TextHeight(vText);
    BM32.FillRect(rRect.Left,rRect.Top,rRect.Right,rRect.Bottom,clWhite);

    if not vCenterText then
      Winapi.Windows.TextOut(BM32.Handle, vLeft + 4, vTop + 2, PChar(vText), Length(vText))
    else
      Winapi.Windows.TextOut(BM32.Handle, vLeft + (vWidth div 2) - (BM32.TextWidth(vText) div 2), vTop + (vHeight div 2) - (BM32.TextHeight(vText) div 2), PChar(vText), Length(vText));
  end;
end;
```